# I want to change button text background

Tags: android, android-studio, button, text

As a beginner in android studio I keep facing a problem that I can't fix, there is a button with background image that I made, what I want to do is I want to add some kind of shadow behind my text background so that it looks more visible and professional.

This is my project so far :

[image]

This is how I want to make the text background look like :

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#2C2929"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#2C2929"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="11sp"
            android:background="@drawable/surveys"
            android:elegantTextHeight="false"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Affiliate Marketing&#10;No.1"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
            android:textColor="#CB252522"
            android:textColorHint="#4A4646"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: Hi @Vetonn, where's your XML code ?, please put it here, so we can help you.

Comment: You can use some libraries like `Glide` to create rounded angles. Or use `CardView` to add shadows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `CardView` + `ImageView` + `TextView` :

```
 <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#fff"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="6dp"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/asian_guy" />

        <TextView
            app:minTxtSize="12sp"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:gravity="start|top"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:background="#5B000000"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Minset"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

**Result :**

[image]

With custom `drawable` :

Create a `drawable` file and name it `button_drawable_bg.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/asian_guy">  <!--ADD YOUR IMAGE HERE-->
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"/>
    </item>
    <item android:top="90dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#5B000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Now in your `Button` XML :

```
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_drawable_bg"
    android:elegantTextHeight="false"
    android:gravity="start|bottom"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:text="Affiliate Marketing\nNo.1"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
    android:textColor="#CBFFFFFF"
    android:textColorHint="#4A4646"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

**Result :**

[image]

Comment: The thing is that I dont want imageview, I have a button that I wanna change, I updated my xml code

Comment: @Vetonn, please add your XML code to your question, I can't see any XML!

Comment: @Vetonn also, it's impossible to achieve your needs (second image) without having a separate `TextView` + `ImageView` and the `CardView` for rounded background

Comment: First button that I send is created by this code, it is button it is not cardview or imageview just a button

Comment: rounded backround I found an easier way to make I didnt need any of that I just found where to cut my picture and make it rounded and it works like a magic for the button, though I just need to add that shadow part behind the textview of the button thats all I need

Comment: I added the code take a look

Comment: @Vetonn please see my updated answer.

Comment: thanks a lot I will try this. Now another question, the thing is that I want to create in the main screen 20 or more buttons like that, Do I need to create a drawable for each button ?

Comment: Every button is going to be the same just the backround picture will be different, not the asian guy but something else

Comment: @Vetonn Then, unfortunately, there's no solution for that, you can't change the `drawable` image programmatically, you need to go with my previous solution (`CardView` + `ImageView` + `TextView`), I don't know why you don't want to use it

Comment: I think I will go with that, I tested both and that one seems much better, just if you can explain me how do I manage to put multiple in cardView as I told you I want to put around 20 do I have to create new relative layout for each one of them ?

Comment: No, you need to use RecyclerView + Adapter, if you don't know how to do that, follow this YouTube tutorial : https://youtu.be/oq_xGMN0mRE it's very easy

Comment: thnx a lot can you update that previous code again

Comment: I think I did, cause Im new here too haha